# Algolia InstantSearch Templating: Displaying attribute of object in array within index record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templating, algolia

I'm using Algolia to search `Post` records in my rails application. Each post `has_many` tag objects. A `Tag` has an `id`, `name`, and other `count`. Here is an example record in my index:

```
{
      "id": 98,
      "caption": "How to Invent the Future I - Alan Kay",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "Startup School",
          "taggings_count": 6
        },
        {
          "id": 49,
          "name": "YCombinator",
          "taggings_count": 7
        }
      ]
}
```

I'm able to search these records by `Tag` name, and would like to display the tags of a hit in my results. I've tried the standard ways of accessing a nested JSON array attribute without any luck - nothing is ever displayed from the tags:

```
{{{_highlightResult.tags[0].name.value}}} # displays nothing

{{{tags[0].name.value}}} # displays nothing

{{{tags[0].name}}} # displays nothing
```

Both of the above should return "Startup School" as that is the first tag. How can I display these nested array object attributes?

Comment: Can you check what did you configure for the `Attributes to highlight` parameter under the `display` tab of your dashboard? If there's nothing, every attribute should appear under `_highlightResult`. If you only want highlighting for tags.name you can also precise this. Also, be careful, this parameter can be override at query time.

Comment: @Marie I don't have anything configured under attributes to highlight. I don't even necessarily need them to be highlighted - I just need the tags on the record to be shown in search results.

Comment: can you see the results of the XHR request sent by Algolia? You should see a hits property that should contained by default everything in your record including the array of tags. Are you seeing it?

Comment: @Marie Yes, I can see the tags array in hits property the XHR response. I can also see a copy of tags array in the _hightlightResult property of each hit.

Comment: That's weird. What library from Algolia are you using to get the results? Can you provide a live example reproducing your issue? Often it helps a lot finding what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access an array like this with mustache templating system.

You should use it like this:

```
instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: document.querySelector('#videos'),
  hitsPerPage: 3,
  templates: {
      item: '<div>{{_highlightResult.caption.value}} - TAGS :  {{#tags}}{{#name}}{{name}} - {{/name}}{{/tags}} </div>'
    }
});
```

or directly with JS:

```
instantsearch.widgets.hits({
  container: document.querySelector('#videos'),
  hitsPerPage: 3,
  templates: {
     item: function(data) {
          const tags = data._highlightResult.tags.map(function(tag){
            return tag.name.value
        })
        return '<div>'+ data._highlightResult.caption.value + ' - ' + tags + '</div>'
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks again for all the help :)